# Product of Integral Ring Homomorphism

Tags: commutative-algebra

It's Exercice 13.25 in Steps in Commutative Algebra.

"Let $R,S_1,...,S_n$ be commutative rings, and suppose that $f_i: R\to S_i$ is an integral ring homomorphism for each i. Show that ring homomorphism $f:R\to \prod_{i=1}^n S_i$" for which $f(r)=(f(r_1),...,f(r_n))$ is integral."

So, my approach is to prove $Im f [(s_1,...,s_n)]$ is a finitely generated $Imf-$module, which is not likely to be the appropriate way since I can't control $Imf$ with $Imf_1,..., Imf_n $. So, help me plz!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use the fact that the composition of integral homomorphisms is integral, I suggest you decompose $f$ as $f=\tilde{f} \circ\Delta,$ where $$\tilde{f}:R^n \rightarrow \prod_{i=1}^nS_i \text{ is given by }\tilde{f}(r_1, \dots, r_n)=(f_1(r_1), \dots, f_n(r_n)), \text{ and }$$
$$\Delta: R \rightarrow R^n \text{ is given by }r \mapsto (r, r, \dots, r).$$

Proving integrality separately for $\tilde{f}$ and $\Delta$ will be easier.

***EDIT (composition of integral homomorphisms is integral):***

I would guess the proof works the same way as with the more usual integral extensions, only with more annoying notation. Let me assume the integral extension version to prove this more general version:

Suppose $f:R \rightarrow S$ and $g: S \rightarrow T$ are integral. Pick $\alpha \in T.$ Then there is a monic relation $\alpha^n+g_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+\dots+g_1\alpha+g_0=0$ with $g_i\in \mathrm{Im}\;g$. Pick preimages $s_i \in S$ of $g_i$'s, i.e. $g(s_i)=g_i.$

Notice that $g((\mathrm{Im}\;f)[s_0, \dots, s_{n-1}])=(\mathrm{Im}\;gf)[g_0, \dots, g_{n-1}]$. Further, we have each $s_i$ integral over $\mathrm{Im}\;{f},$ hence each $g_i$ is integral over $\mathrm{Im}\;{gf}=g(\mathrm{Im}{f})$: just take the monic relation for $s_i$ over $\mathrm{Im}{f}$ and apply $g$ to it. Thus, we have $\mathrm{Im}\;{gf} \subseteq (\mathrm{Im}\;{gf})[g_0, \dots, g_{n-1}] \subseteq (\mathrm{Im}\;{gf})[g_0, \dots, g_{n-1}][\alpha]$ a tower of integral extensions, hence $\mathrm{Im}\;{gf} \subseteq (\mathrm{Im}\;{gf})[g_0, \dots, g_{n-1}][\alpha]$ is an integral extension by the standard theorem. In particular, $\alpha$ is integral over $\mathrm{Im}\;{gf}$.

Comment: Yeah I did think about this idea. But I don't think composition of integral homomorphism is integral. Can u show me?

Comment: @chítrungchâu I added a proof of the fact that composition of integral homomorphisms is an integral homomorphism based on the same assertion for integral _extensions_ (which works and is fairly standard).

Comment: How do we show that $\tilde{f}$ is integral?

Comment: @Ninja Given $(s_1, \dots s_n) \in \prod_i S_i,$ for each $s_i$ one has a monic relation $X^{d_i}=\sum_{j<d_i}t_{ij} X^j$ such that all $t_{ij}$ lie in the image of $f_i: R \rightarrow S_i,$ say $t_{ij}=f_i(r_{ij}),$ $r_{ij}\in R$. WLOG one may consider all the degrees $d_i$, equal to some $d$ (just multiply the relations by a suitable power of $X$ when needed). Then the whole bunch $(s_1, \dots, s_n)$ satisfies the monic relation $X^d=\sum_{j < n}(t_{1j}, \dots t_{n j}) \cdot X^j,$ and the coefficients $(t_{1j}, \dots t_{nj})=\tilde{f}(r_{1j}, \dots r_{nj})$ are in the image of $\tilde{f}$.